# npyscreen com acessibilidade

Tags: python-3.x

Estou ajudando um colega que é cego a programar em Python!

Ele utiliza o bloco de notas e um leitor de telas chamado **nvda** (escrito em Python).

Estamos com dificuldade no formulário de cadastro porque o nvda está lendo (com o sintetizador de voz) apenas o título do formulário: "Agenda Retrô".

Alguém conhece alguma forma de fazer com que todos os textos do **npyscreen** sejam lidos pelo **nvda**?

Qualquer solução alternativa será muito bem vinda.

Grato pela atenção, Abraço!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import npyscreen

class TestApp(npyscreen.NPSApp):

    def main(self):
        F  = npyscreen.Form(name = "Agenda Retrô")
        nome = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Nome:", )
        sobrenome = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Sobrenome:", )
        residencial = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Residencial:", )
        celular = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Celular:", )
        email = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Email:", )
        endereco = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Endereco:", )
        complemento = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Complemento:", )
        estado = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Estado:", )
        municipio = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Municipio:", )        
        nota = F.add(npyscreen.MultiLineEdit, 
               value = """Escreva aqui...\n""", 
               max_height=5, rely=12)
        F.edit()

        print(nome.value)
        print(sobrenome.value)
        print(residencial.value)
        print(celular.value)
        print(email.value)
        print(endereco.value)
        print(complemento.value)
        print(estado.value)
        print(municipio.value)
        print(nota.value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = TestApp()
    App.run()
```

Comment: Visto que o `npyscreen` utiliza o módulo [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) do python, você poderia pesquisar se existe acessibilidade e como ela funciona em outras fontes...

Comment: O site estava em manutenção, quando eu escrevi o comentário o Willian ainda não tinha respondido a questão. :|

Comment: Grato fernandosavio pela ajuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente a lib npyscreen não tem opções de acessibilidade, assim como  90% das libs gráficas do python.

Unica lib de bibliotecas gráficas acessível a deficientes visuais que conheço é a wxpython.

Comment: Olá Willian, 
Vou testar com wxpython. 
Abraço!